# Tug Of War: Divide set of n objects int to subsets

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, bit-manipulation, dynamic-programming

I found a problem of Tug Of War while doing some algorithm practice on Internet:

**Statement**:

Given a set of n integers, divide the set in two subsets of n/2 sizes each such that the difference of the sum of two subsets is as minimum as possible. If n is even, then sizes of two subsets must be strictly n/2 and if n is odd, then size of one subset must be (n-1)/2 and size of other subset must be (n+1)/2.

For example, let given set be

```
{3, 4, 5, -3, 100, 1, 89, 54, 23, 20}
```

the size of set is 10. Output for this set should be

```
{4, 100, 1, 23, 20}
```

and

```
{3, 5, -3, 89, 54}
```

Both output subsets are of size 5 and sum of elements in both subsets is same (148 and 148).

Let us consider another example where n is odd. Let given set be

```
{23, 45, -34, 12, 0, 98, -99, 4, 189, -1, 4}
```

The output subsets should be

```
{45, -34, 12, 98, -1}
```

and

```
{23, 0, -99, 4, 189, 4}
```

The sums of elements in two subsets are 120 and 121 respectively.

I found a knapsack kind of approach on Internet while looking for solution [here](https://github.com/ajahuang/UVa/blob/master/UVa%2010032%20-%20Tug%20of%20War.cpp):

I'm not getting this part of the solution:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    for (int j = sum; j >= 0; --j)
        if (dp[j])
            dp[j + W[i]] |= dp[j] << 1;
```

I understand that we are trying to find the number of objects that have accounted for a sum of i. But doing `dp[i] << 1` is something I'm not getting properly:

Also, why are we iterating the j variable backwards, starting from sum to 0? Why not 0 to sum ?

Can someone please tell me underlying logic in more simple and generalized way ?

Thanks

Comment: Often, iterating backwards is done because the operations on lower-index elements destroy or invalidate higher-index elements.  The higher-index elements therefore have to be processed first.

Answer (score 3):

I think the comment makes it pretty clear, actually.

```
 // If (dp[i] << j) & 1 is 1, that means it is possible
 // to select j out of the N people so that the sum of
 // their weight is i.
```

You start with the initial condition dp[0] = 1 << 0, meaning "it's possible to select 0 people such that the sum of their weight is 0".

Then for each entry in dp that's nonzero (that's the `if (dp[j])` part), you update dp for the current person in the list.

Now, you're specifically asking "why `dp[j] << 1`"? Well, imagine the first 3 elements are 1, 2, 3.

Then dp[3] will be 110 in binary, meaning "you can make a sum of 3 using 1 person (3), OR two people (1 and 2).

If the next number is 10, then when we come to dp[3], we do `dp[3+10] |= dp[3] << 1`, making dp[13] 1100. Meaning "since we can make 3 with either 2 people or one person, with an extra 10 in the mix, we can make 13 with either 3 people (1, 2, 10) or 2 people (3, 10)"

Then at the end, all you need to do is look for the entry in dp which is closest to half of the total sum. And of course, the other team's sum will be the total sum minus this value.

Note that this algorithm will NOT tell you which numbers you need to pick to get that sum; that information is lost. It will only tell you what the best two sums are. Though it would not be hard to modify the algorithm slightly and use some data structure to retain that information (such that each entry in dp says "I can make this sum from 3 numbers, *and these numbers are...*").

Oh, and about the iterating backwards: that's to prevent us from counting the same number twice. If the first entry was 1, we'd say "I can make 0 from 0 numbers; now I can make 1 from 1 number". Then immediately afterwards, "I can make 1 from 1 number; now I can make 2 from 2 numbers". And so on.

EDIT: since you asked, here's one way of doing this (note that it will break if you enter non-positive numbers, I'll leave it to you to fix that):

```
int N;
int W[100 + 5];
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> dp[450 * 100 + 5];

void solve()
{
    int sum = accumulate(W + 1, W + N + 1, 0);

    // If (dp[i][j]) contains a nonempty vector, that means it is possible
    // to select j out of the N people so that the sum of
    // their weight is i, with those people's indices being the values of said vector
    dp[W[1]][1].push_back(1);

    for (int i = 2; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = sum; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            for (std::map<int, std::vector<int>>::iterator it = dp[j].begin(); it != dp[j].end(); ++it)
            {
                dp[j + W[i]][it->first+1] = it->second;
                dp[j + W[i]][it->first+1].push_back(i);
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> selected;
    int minDiff = 450 * 100;
    int teamOneWeight = 0, teamTwoWeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= sum; ++i)
    {
        if (!dp[i].empty())
        {
            int diff = abs(i - (sum - i));
            if (diff < minDiff)
            {
                minDiff = diff;
                teamOneWeight = i;
                teamTwoWeight = sum-i;
                selected = dp[i].begin()->second;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Team 1, sum of " << teamOneWeight << ": ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        if (std::find(selected.begin(), selected.end(), i) != selected.end())
            cout << W[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl << "Team 1, sum of " << teamTwoWeight << ": ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        if (std::find(selected.begin(), selected.end(), i) == selected.end())
            cout << W[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: How can we modify the algorithm to store what all elements are there which are generating a particular sum ?

Answer (score 1):

### Basic approach

This approach can be thought of as using dynamic programming to compute the contents of the 3 dimensional array f.

f is defined as:

`f[i][sum][j] = 1` if it is possible to use j of the weights in the range 1..i to produce a total weight of sum.

Now suppose we know `f[i][sum][j]` is 1 for some values of i,sum,j.  If we decide to include weight i, then we deduce that `f[i+1][sum+W[i]][j+1]` must also be true.

```
f[i+1][sum+W[i]][j+1] |= f[i][sum][j]
```

If we don't include weight i, then we deduce that `f[i+1][sum][j]` must also be true.

### Optimization 1

The first optimization is to store the third dimension in a single 64bit integer instead of in 64 1 bit integers.  This makes the code run much faster.

Suppose f[i][sum] = binary 1001, this means that f[i][sum][j] is 1 for j equal to 0 or 3.  We now conclude that we need to set f[i][sum+w[i]][j] equal to 1 for j equal to 1 or 4, so we need to OR with binary 10010 = 1001<<1, this explains the <<1 operation.

### Optimization 2

The second optimization is to spot that we can reuse the same array for all values of i, however to do this we need to iterate backwards otherwise we will think that we can use the ith element multiple times.